# Autodesk Forge Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am writing this because i need to improve productivity in the company that I work for.
I made several applications for internal use with Visual Studio VB.NET, but at this time i am thinking about this:

- I have some DWG drawings with blocks and attributes that i use as templates.
  On the other hand I have an Excel worksheet  with columns that start with a number in the first row and the values below. Each row number corresponds to an attribute in a  block inside of each DWG template.
  I want to fill those attributes with the Excel sheet values . I already made it locally but it will be good to make it in a cloud.
  Is it possible with Autodesk Forge?
  How?
  I really need you to help me.
  Best regards
  Luis

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with Design Automation, I see that you already have a working application in AutoCAD, does your application is tested in accoreconsole ? That comes with AutoCAD installation.

Comment: Not tested. I had a trial forge but is expired, never used it. How can i build that application in Forge?. Can we make a ZOOM meeting?

Comment: Yes, feel free to book -https://calendly.com/autodeskforge/madhukar-moogala?month=2021-10

Comment: Already schedule the meeting. Thank you!